# What is the battle song from "Star Trek Beyond" and is there any significance to it appearing in "Star Trek" of 2009?

Tags: star-trek, behind-the-scenes, star-trek-beyond

I was watching *Star Trek Beyond* the other day, and couldn't help but notice that the song that plays during the final space battle, sounds exactly like the song playing during the car chase and crash sequence with young Kirk in *Star Trek* from 2009.

Out-of-universe, is there a reason why this song has been re-used? Is this a homage to someone, or a part of Star Trek history I'm oblivious to?

Comment: the creators like beasty boys.

Comment: In the first movie it was probably just used as a "young, rebellious" song to suit Kirk's personality at the time. Its use in Beyond is almost certainly due to the thematic connection. They needed "something loud" to interfere with (ie: to sabotage) the drone frequency.  Enter the Beastie Boys.  Whether this was coincidence or not, it will probably become a running gag going forward (at least the use of Beastie Boys music, if not this particular song.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## The song is "Sabotage" by the Beastie Boys

According to [Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Sabotage_(song)), it was produced on Earth by Humans in the late 20th century.

It is exactly the same song that was used in the chase scene in *Star Trek (2009)*.

It was creators' choice to include this song in the *Star Trek Beyond*. Other songs have also been considered, for example from *[Creedence Clearwater Revival](http://www.empireonline.com/movies/features/star-trek-beyond-justin-lin-simon-pegg/)*, proposed by the director, Justin Lin. (emphasis mine):

> I actually was trying to get Creedence Clearwater Revival in there. But it didn't feel right. The third track [we tried] was Sabotage. Once it got in there, it never changed. **It was in the DNA of the franchise** – it also calls back to Kirk's childhood.

The song has also been used in the *Star Trek Beyond* trailer and for that Simon Pegg felt that:

> they blew that. That's our little funny secret weapon. I was kind of ticked off about it. It's the Ewoks against the Empire! It's defeating something technological with something very simple – with just a radio frequency.

[(source)](http://www.empireonline.com/movies/features/star-trek-beyond-justin-lin-simon-pegg/)

Comment: I don't recall who picked the song in Beyond. Was it Kirk? Maybe that's just his favorite song.

Comment: @DCShannon  -  nah, it was Jaylah.